# SQL Upgrade Adviser for win2k

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server

I'm trying to upgrade a SQL Server 2000 instance to SQL Server 2008 R2. SQL Server 2000 resides on an old win2k box, and the new SQL instance is being run on a Server 2008 R2 platform. I am attempting to use Microsoft's SQL Upgrade Adviser tool to determine if I will run into any compatibility issues during the migration.

The tool can be installed on a minimum of a Server 2003 platform, which means that I cannot run the adviser on the win2k box locally. I have read that I can generate trace files on the SQL 2000 instance, and then have the adviser analyze those, but I have been unable to figure out how to point the tool to the trace files. It seems that I am only allowed to point to a locally installed database, which doesn't exactly help in my situation...

Am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620269/migrate-from-sql-server-2000-to-2008-r2-how-to) for a better way...sometimes "manual" is better.

Comment: `I'm trying to upgrade a SQL Server 2000 instance to SQL Server 2008 R2. SQL Server 2000 resides on an old win2k box, and the new SQL instance is being run on a Server 2008 R2 platform.` - That doesn't make sense. How can this be an upgrade if you have two separate instances of SQL Server? Do you mean that you're trying to migrate your databases from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: That is what I meant - migrating from 2000 to 2008 R2... Turns out, the upgrade did not require any manual intervention, for the app that used the database automatically upgraded the database upon a fresh install of the software. It would have been nice if the documentation would have indicated that...